# Oracle floating average

Tags: sql, oracle, average

I got this little statement in my select which calculates the difference in minutes. Both are `date`.

```
 ((Cars.Closed - Costomer.BookedDate)*24* 60) differnece_in_minutes
```

This in my result:

```
  differnece_in_minutes
  340
  23
  10
  4500
  245
```

Using `AVG(((Cars.Closed - Costomer.BookedDate)*24* 60)) differnece_in_minutes`
gives me the average value. So far no problem.

But I would like to calculate the `floating average` - not the basic `average`.

I found some stuff in the web but I don't know exactly which function to use and how.

I want it to ignore values that are extremely high or low compared to the "normal" average.

I found stuff like `moving`, `rolling` average.

Comment: What is a "floating average"?

Comment: It will help if you provide sample data and the expected results to show us what you mean.

Comment: Just values that are kinda rarely - like an "aberration" - extremly low or high. For example the '4500' in my result which would distort my "average" I hope you know what I mean.

Comment: It sounds like you want to exclude significant outliers.  One example is to calculate the mean and the standard deviation in a first pass, then exclude anything that is outside mean +/- (n) standard deviations.  Depending on the nature of your data you need to tune the value of (n).  Also, if your data is normally distributed you may find that this incidentally excludes data that isn't "abnormal".  In short, you need to read some stats texts, pick an algorithm and then come here to ask how to implement it.

Comment: What @replay MatBailie says is what I mean. Is there any ready function in Oracle to do this job?

Comment: By way of an example as to the difficulty in picking an algorithm without any knowledge of the space you are working in; what if the values 10, 23, 245 ad 340 are the "abnormal" values, excluding the 4500 would be a mistake.  *(How can you be sure that a data set with both good and bad data is dominated by the good data?)*.  Equally, if you exclude the 4500, then do the 245 and 340 now look like anomalies and also need excluding?  *(And if you repeat this, would yo eliminate nearly all the data?)*

Comment: @piguy - No there is no pre-made function because the definition of "aberration" depends on the context and business rules.  ***You*** need to pick an algorithm, heuristic, business rule, and then use the stats functions *(or other functions)* in SQL to implement it.  There is ***no one single answer / definition*** to this problem.

Comment: For instance; the standard deviation of your set is 1948; a standard method of removing outliers would be to use the [3-sigma rule of thumb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/68%E2%80%9395%E2%80%9399.7_rule), which would remove nothing...

Comment: Thanks for all your answers guys - you helped me a lot! :-) question answered!

Answer (score 2):

In case you are looking for "moving" or "rolling" average you can use the windowing clause, example:

```
WITH t AS 
    (SELECT 1 AS N, 10 AS val FROM dual
    UNION ALL SELECT 2, 20 FROM dual
    UNION ALL SELECT 3, 20 FROM dual
    UNION ALL SELECT 4, 30 FROM dual
    UNION ALL SELECT 5, 25 FROM dual
    UNION ALL SELECT 6, 35 FROM dual
    UNION ALL SELECT 7, 33 FROM dual
    UNION ALL SELECT 8, 18 FROM dual
    UNION ALL SELECT 9, 1500 FROM dual
    UNION ALL SELECT 10, 15 FROM dual)
SELECT N, Val,
    AVG(val) OVER (ORDER BY N ROWS BETWEEN 2 PRECEDING AND 2 FOLLOWING) AS rolling_average
FROM t;


         N        VAL ROLLING_AVERAGE
---------- ---------- ---------------
         1         10      16.6666667
         2         20              20
         3         20              21
         4         30              26
         5         25            28.6
         6         35            28.2
         7         33           322.2
         8         18           320.2
         9       1500           391.5
        10         15             511

10 rows selected.
```

For example, row 6 is the average of rows 4 to 8, i.e. AVG(30,25,35,33,18)